# Why can't I call a method?

Tags: ruby

So I thought I'd learn some Ruby. I was playing with the interpreter but I wanted to make bigger programs so I downloaded Aptana, an IDE. When I try to run this code:

```
class HelloWorld
    def h
        puts "hello World!"
    end
    h
end
```

It gives me an error that says h is an undefined local variable. When I type the commands into the interpreter (without the class start and end) it calls h the way I want it to.

I'm at a loss here. what's going on?

Comment: Congratulations on asking the 20,000th Ruby question on Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 3):

While defining a class, the methods you define are `instance` methods. This means you would call them like so:

```
class HelloWorld
  def h
    puts "hello world!"
  end
end

instance = HelloWorld.new
instance.h
```

Ruby is complaining that your method doesn't exist because, whilst defining a class body, any function calls made are to `class` methods (or `singleton` methods).

If you really wanted to do this, you would do it like so:

```
class HelloWorld
  def self.h
    puts "hello World!"
  end
  h
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you've sent the `h` message whilst in `class` scope. (I'm sure some folks with more Ruby experience will want to correct my wording here; also, if I'm entirely wrong, accept my apologies.)

You can send `h` from another instance method on `HelloWorld`:

```
class HelloWorld
  def h; puts "hello world!"; end

  def g
    h
  end
end

HelloWorld.new.g
# => "hello world!"
```

Comment: You don't really need to wrap method h within g like that. You can omit the method g and its definition and just call h by issuing "HelloWorld.new.h"

Comment: Of course! I was just showing the OP how to call a method from within a class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class HelloWorld
  def self.h
    puts "hello World!"
  end
  h # you can only call h like this if it is defined as a class method above
end

HelloWorld.h # you can call the class method like this also
```

You need to define h as a class method to call it like that. ALternatively, you can do this

```
class HelloWorld
  def h
    puts "hello World!"
  end
end

a = HelloWorld.new # instantiate a new instance of HelloWorld
a.h
```

Good luck!

Comment: In the `self.h` example, you can call method `h` from inside the class.